# ¿Cómo actualizo el Amazon AWS SDK a una versión compatible (Gradle)?

Tags: java, aws, gradle, sdk

He encontrado varias referencias en Amazon AWS support pero no consigo sacar nada en claro.

Una o más aplicaciones de su cuenta se conectan a los servicios de AWS mediante una versión anterior de AWS SDK for Java que es incompatible con Transport Layer Security (TLS) versión 1.3. Actualice sus aplicaciones Java a AWS SDK for Java versión 1.12.x o posterior para habilitar la compatibilidad con TLS 1.3.

Hemos estado usando este build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    ext {


        dependencyManagementPluginVersion = '1.0.3.RELEASE'
        springBootVersion = '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:${dependencyManagementPluginVersion}"

        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"

    }
}

subprojects {


    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            credentials {
                username 
                password 
            }
            url 'https://---'
        }
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Si no das más infromación como qué errores estás teniendo, por poner un ejemplo, va a estar dificil que obtengas respuestas

Comment: Te está diciendo que para usar TLS 1.3 necesitas usar java `1.12.x` o superior. Tu gradle indica que usas  java 8 (`1.8`). Cambia la versión de java en tu gradle y listo... Por supuesto, *"y listo"* implica revisar todos los imports de spring y asegurarte de que indicas versiones compatibles :)